# Python Pandas Не получается решить задачу

Tags: python, pandas, анализ

Решаю задачу на https://py.checkio.org/ru/mission/the-cheapest-flight/, но не могу понять как сделать суммирование. Хочу решить эту задачу именно через Pandas.

Cуть задачи,  вывести из фрейма сумму столбца,  если входные параметры совпадают с переданными строками.   Вот пример переданного List и двух аргументов str. Функция должна возвращать сумму столбца, если переданные аргументы совпадают. При этом вывести нужно минимум. Конкретно в данном примере должно быть выведено 60

```
from typing import List
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def cheapest_flight(costs: List, a: str, b: str) -> int:
    df = pd.DataFrame(costs)
    price1, price2, price3, price4, price5, price6 = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    for item in costs:
        if a or b in item:
            price1 = df.loc[(df[0]== a) & (df[1]== b) | (df[0]== b) & (df[1]== a),2].sum()
            price3 = df.loc[(df[0]== a) & (df[1]!= b),2 & (df[2]==df[0]) ].sum()
            price4 = df.loc[(df[0]!= a) & (df[1]== b),2].sum()
            price5 = df.loc[(df[0]!= b) & (df[1]== a),2].sum()
            price6 = df.loc[(df[0]!= a) & (df[1]== b),2].sum()
    print(df)
    return price1, price2, price3, price4, price5, price6
            
print(cheapest_flight(
  [['A', 'C', 40],
  ['A', 'B', 20],
  ['A', 'D', 20],
  ['B', 'C', 50],
  ['D', 'C', 70]],
 'D',
 'C'))
```

У меня получается значение неверное
Спасибо, если укажите мне на мою ошибку.

Comment: Мне не ясно, как у вас получилось число 70.

Comment: по условиям задачи должно получится 70
На входе вы получаете расписание самолётов в виде массива, каждый элемент которого — это цена прямого воздушного соединения двух городов (массив из 3 элементов: первые два — названия городов в виде строк, и третий — цена перелёта).

Самолёты летают в обе стороны и цена в обе стороны одинаковая. Есть вероятность, что соединения между городами может и не быть.

Найдите цену самого дешёвого перелёта для городов, которые переданы 2-м и 3-м аргументами.

Comment: Значит, вы в корне не верно сформулировали вопрос. в ваших табличных данных нет значения 70, его нужно вычислять алгоритмом поиска пути. то есть, pandas в таком виде сама по себе вам не поможет решить задачу.  вот у вас и получается какая-то "пурга".

Comment: Cпасибо,  а как тогда вычислить. Простите за глупый вопрос.

Comment: Это вам в сторону графов нужно смотреть, мне кажется: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html